# Does CAML Query has a default RowLimit value?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, caml, sharepoint-list

I am wondering wether SharePoint CAML Query has a default Rowlimit value. I have created a list which will contain more than 10 000 items in a near future. I use a CAML Query on client-side to export the items to a custom file. The query does not specify any RowLimit.
So will the query succeed if I have more than 10 000 items in my list ?

Comment: @Greg yes it helped. I'll use pagings. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The success of query execution depends on 'List View Threshold' settings:). If 'List View Threshold' is greater than number of items in the list then you should be fine. Maybe it is a good idea to use paging with queries that returns such big amount of results?

You can find more details about list throttling on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx)